# Django: No module named 'project'

Tags: python, django

I was working on a Django project on my personal laptop. Then I cloned the project to my work laptop and I'm getting a very weird error when I try to run any command, such as `python manage.py runserver`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/jmetz/github/personal/golf-swings-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/jmetz/github/personal/golf-swings-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/jmetz/github/personal/golf-swings-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 336, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/Users/jmetz/github/personal/golf-swings-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 219, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "/Users/jmetz/github/personal/golf-swings-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 213, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "/Users/jmetz/github/personal/golf-swings-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/jmetz/github/personal/golf-swings-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 147, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "/Users/jmetz/github/personal/golf-swings-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/jmetz/github/personal/golf-swings-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/jmetz/github/personal/golf-swings-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/Users/jmetz/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'
```

Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: can you share your directory structure of project

Comment: It's exactly the same as any other django starter project but nothing is named `project` so I imagine it's some internal problem with Django or Miniconda? Cause my personal laptop uses python installed from homebrew.

Comment: can you display your installed_apps list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add project to your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py file

```
settings.py

    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'project',
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution to a similar problem was to export PYTHONPATH into my shell. That was throwing a warning about project, even though the INSTALLED_APPS was correct.