# update user profile issue with post_save signal. errors a message are user already exists on update

Tags: django

I have extending user profile with profile model and create an post_save signal.

I works well on user creation but seems that there is an issue on update. When I want to update I have messages saying user and email already exists in data table. So nothing is updated. and and send back to Register page but should go to edit_profile page

My model.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from authenticate.thumbs import ImageWithThumbsField  # transforme les images en thumbs
import os


def image_name(instance, filename):
    extension = filename.split('.')
    extension = extension[-1]
    return 'avatars/{}.{}'.format(instance.user.pk, extension)


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = ImageWithThumbsField(upload_to=image_name,  blank=True)  # transforme les images en thumbs
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, default='Please fill in info')
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()
```

My forms.py:

```
class UniqueUserEmailField(forms.EmailField):
    """
    An EmailField which only is valid if no User has that email.
    """
    def validate(self, value):
        super(forms.EmailField, self).validate(value)
        try:
            User.objects.get(email = value)
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email already exists")
        except User.MultipleObjectsReturned:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email already exists")
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            pass


class SignUpform(UserCreationForm):
    """
    Extends the built in UserCreationForm in several ways:

    * Adds an email field, which uses the custom UniqueUserEmailField,
      that is, the form does not validate if the email address already exists
      in the User table.
    * The username field is generated based on the email, and isn't visible.
    * first_name and last_name fields are added.
    * Data not saved by the default behavior of UserCreationForm is saved.
    * add forms control from Bootstrap to improve form UX
    """

    email = forms.EmailField(required= True, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Email address' }))
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='',max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First Name', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='',max_length=100,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Last Name', 'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name',  'password1', 'password2',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignUpform, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

        # change labels

        self.fields['username'].label = ''
        self.fields['username'].help_text = '<span class="form-text text-muted"><small>Required.</small></span>'
        self.fields['email'].help_text = '<span class="form-text text-muted"><small>Required.</small></span>'
        self.fields['password1'].label = ''
        self.fields['password1'].help_text = '<ul class="form-text text-muted small">' \
                                             '<li>Your password cannot be too similar to your other personal information.</li>' \
                                             '<li>Your password must contain at least 8 characters.</li>' \
                                             '<li>Your password cannot be a commonly used password.</li>' \
                                             '<li>Your password cannot be entirely numeric.</li>' \
                                             '</ul>'
        self.fields['password2'].label = ''
        self.fields['password2'].help_text = '<span class="form-text text-muted"><small>Enter the same password as before, for verification.</small></span>'
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'User Name'
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'password'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'confirm password'

    def clean_email(self):
        # Get the email
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

        # Check to see if any users already exist with this email as a username.
        try:
            match = User.objects.get(email=email)
            print("ok")
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            # Unable to find a user, this is fine
            return email

        # A user was found with this as a username, raise an error.
        raise forms.ValidationError('This email address is already in use.')


class EditUseform(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password',)



class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('avatar', 'bio', 'location', 'birth_date')
        widgets = {
            'birth_date': DatePickerInput(),  # default date-format %m/%d/%Y will be used

        }
```

My views.py:

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpform(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            # modify existing profile
            profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user.pk)
            profile.avatar = profile_form.cleaned_data['avatar']
            profile.bio = profile_form.cleaned_data['bio']
            profile.location = profile_form.cleaned_data['location']
            profile.birth_date = profile_form.cleaned_data['birth_date']

            profile.save()

            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, 'You are registered')
            # redirect to a succes page
            return redirect('home')

    else:
        form = SignUpform()
        profile_form = ProfileForm()

    context = {'form': form,
    'profile_from': profile_form, }
    return render(request, 'register.html', context)


def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditUseform(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST,  instance=request.user.profile)
        if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # modify existing profile
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, _('Your profile was successfully     updated!'))
            # redirect to a succes page
            return redirect('edit_Profile')

    else:
        form = EditUseform(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)

        context = {'form': form,
               'profile_from': profile_form, }
        return render(request, 'edit_Profile.html', context)
```

My Edit_Profille.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<!---- datepicker ---->
{% block extrahead %}
{{ profile_from.media }}
{% endblock %}
<!-------->

{% block content %}
<h2 class="text-center">Edit user</h2>

 <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">

<form   method="POST" action="{% url 'register' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    {% csrf_token %}

    {% if form.errors %}

        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable" role="alert">
            <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
                <small><sup>x</sup></small>
            </button>
          <p>Your form has errors:</p>
            {%  for field in form %}
                {% if field.errors %}
                    {{  field.errors }}
                {%  endif %}
            {%  endfor %}
        </div>


    {%  endif %}

    {{ form.as_p }}
    {{ profile_from.as_p }}

        <input type="submit" value="register" class="btn btn-primary">

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you share the stack trace?

Comment: could you tell me how to do that..I m new bee

Comment: The stacktrace that you get in your log when the error occurs. It looks like the blob of text in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57344207/django-no-module-named-project

Comment: there is no error in the code. I've go messages in my html page:
Your form has errors:

This email address is already in use.
A user with that username already exists.
This field is required.
This field is required.
This field is required.
This field is required.

Comment: Which view/form is being used?

Comment: views: should be edit_profile and form: 2 forms in :EditUseform and ProfileForm

Comment: You probably shouldn't have your update form posting to the register view `action="{% url 'register' %}"`. This should be posting to your update view

Comment: I use  from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm in forms.py

Comment: forms used for update is :EditUseform(UserChangeForm):

Comment: Can you try changing the forms action attribute?

Comment: How can I do that ?

Comment: In your template `<form  method="POST" action="{% url 'register' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">`. I'm almost certain the action is wrong